# Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null value - Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a problem and is when I updated my project asp .net core 2.1 to 3.1 I always get this error in my project angular  when y try to send some data.

```
ClassName: "System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException"
Data: null
ExceptionMethod: null
HResult: -2146232015
HelpURL: null
InnerException: null
Message: "Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values."
RemoteStackIndex: 0
RemoteStackTraceString: null
Source: "Microsoft.Data.SqlClient"
StackTraceString: "   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.ThrowIfNull()\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_String()\r\n   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetString(Int32 i)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , ResultContext , Int32[] , ResultCoordinator )\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryingEnumerable`1.Enumerator.MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   at MotorCredito.Pegasus.Persistence.Repository.MantenimientoLogsRepository.GetIdRegistro() in C:\\Repositorios MC\\Pegasus\\MotorCredito.Pegasus.Persistence\\Repository\\Logs\\MantenimientoLogsRepository.cs:line 91\r\n   at MotorCredito.Pegasus.Web.Controllers.MarcasController.Update(String usuario, Marca marca) in C:\\Repositorios MC\\Pegasus\\MotorCredito.Pegasus.Web\\Controllers\\MarcasController.cs:line 138"
WatsonBuckets: null
```

This is my ConfigureService in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
       // options.JsonSerializerOptions.

    });

    //FORMA NUEVA
    services.AddControllers(options =>
    {
        options.EnableEndpointRouting = true;
        options.SuppressImplicitRequiredAttributeForNonNullableReferenceTypes = true;
        options.AllowEmptyInputInBodyModelBinding = true;

    })
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
        options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver();
        options.SerializerSettings.DateFormatString = "dd-MM-yyyy";
    });

    // ===== Add DbContext Configuration for PegasusDbContext ========
    services.AddDbContextPool<PegasusDbContext>(options =>
       options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PegasusDb")));

    // ===== Add DbContext Configuration for ServicesDbContext========
    services.AddDbContextPool<ServicesDbContext>(options =>
       options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ServicesDb"),
       sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(180)));
```

This is my function Configure

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseCors(x => x.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader());

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseSession();

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    //se agrego esto
    app.UseRouting();

    //se agrego esto
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseFileServer();

    //se agrego esto
    app.UseEndpoints(endPoints =>
    {
        endPoints.MapHub<UserInSolicitudHub>("/UserInSolicitud");
        endPoints.MapControllerRoute(
              name: "default",
           pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
           );
    });


    //app.UseAzureSignalR(routes =>
    //{
    //    routes.MapHub<UserInSolicitudHub>("/UserInSolicitud");
    //});
}
```

I have tried to put some configurations in the function ConfigureServices but I get another errors.

Comment: Hi @Dani, which line makes such error?

Comment: when  i make a request in any endPoint

Answer (score 0):

My answer is a bit late, but I just had the same problem and found the root cause.

This error occurs generally due to Code First Entity framework, when your Entity Model is not defined correctly and mismatches with the Database schema and data.

Specifically in .Net a value type property, like an INT cannot be NULL.

**My specific example;**

My database had a column;

- AccountId INT NULL

My EF Model Object had a property;

- public AccountId int { get; set; }

I was attempting to load an object where the value in AccountID was NULL.

The problem is when EF attempts to put a NULL into a value type it throws the SqlNullValueException.

**The fix - DB**

The DB fix would be to make the column as follows;

- AccountId INT NOT NULL

**The fix - EF Model**

Or you can fix in your model by using a nullable type

- public int? AccountId { get; set; }

Either way the EF Model now matches your DB schema and you will no longer get this error.

Hope this helps